# Getting the path of a remote rsync depot

Tags: daemon, rsync

I know if you run in rsync

`rsync some.domain.com::`

It will return me a list of the rsync depots. Is there any way of getting it to return the details of the depot, the path specifically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, rsyncd is specifically designed not to reveal the physical path of the modules. Now, if you have shell access to the rsyncd server, you can read `/etc/rsyncd.conf` for that information.

(But, there may be ways to exploit rsyncd to reveal the path, if the `use chroot` setting is off. Don't quote me on that, though.)